# Git PR Merge and Resulting Branch is Different

Tags: git, merge, azure-devops

TL/DR: We merged git branch `master` into `production` and the resulting source code was different. Why?

Using an Azure DevOps Pull-Request we merged (FF) our `master` branch (at commit `01785665a`) into `production`, deployed `production` to PROD and went home feeling sure that we'd achieved our goal of pushing staged and tested changes on `master` to production. Imagine our surprise when we discover production is not identical to staging but has some old code.

How can 2 branches be merged and not be identical?? The last commit `01785665a` on `master` has my latest changes and is correct but these changes are NOT in the merge commit of `c1aa29bda`!?

Judging from the DevOps diagram below we did not merge in from master but some commit `c503afc9` (from Apr 27) but perhaps Azure Devops has a confusing graphic (it's not clear which branches the vertical lines refer to). The other graphics show master `01785665a` being merged in.

Git is convinced that production is up to date with master: `git merge master` (on production) => `Already up to date`

#### git log (production)

```
commit c1aa29bda... (HEAD -> production, origin/production)
Merge: 2095cbd 0178566
Date:   Wed Jun 3 10:14:15 2020 +0000

    R4 Release
```

#### git log (master)

```
commit 01785665a... (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Merge: bdc6c56 a5e1d32
Date:   Wed May 13 11:03:43 2020 +0000

    Merged PR 13135: v1.6.6 ...
```

[image: azure devops graph]

[image: VSCode git graph]

[image: Git Extensions Graph]

Comment: You've hidden all the info, so it's hard to help. But do you know what a merge _is_? I mean, let's look at your merge commit: it has two parents, 2095cbd and 0178566. You have not shown either of those commits in your graph (though the second one is clearly `master`). But do you understand what it means to make a merge commit from those two commits? Maybe your expectations are wrong.

Comment: In any case, it would help a lot if you could get specific. Since git lets you look directly into a commit, do that. Look into commits 2095cbd and 0178566 and examine the contents of some individual file that you are troubled by in the outcome on `production`. Tell us what's in that file in 2095cbd and what's in that file in 0178566 and what's in the file in the outcome in `production` and let's talk in specific terms about why `production` came out that way.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need more details - suffice it to say that I expect the contents of ALL files to be identical after a merge. Am I hopelessly off base here? Or is a merge the wrong approach to me wanting to freeze the state of master onto the HEAD of a new branch production so I can deploy HEAD of production and have a history of what I deployed?

Comment: I don't need more details, except in order to understand what you mean. You keep using the word "identical". I don't think it means what you think it means. :) Identical to _what?_ This is a _merge._ There are two different branches involved as parents. The resulting merge commit is not going to be identical to _either_ of them. If it were, this would not be a merge with two parents. That is why I am suggesting you give a specific example of what you expected and what actually happened, so that we can straighten out the issue. If you don't want help, don't do so.

Comment: When I use the word "merge" in this context I mean: take the *state* of all files on `master` and copy them to `production` so production is identical to master. Is merge the wrong tool for the job. Do you understand what I am trying to accomplish? namely: copy this "version" of the branch to another branch for later reference.

Comment: Okay, so the word you're using incorrectly turns out to be not "identical" but "merge". A merge merges (hence the name) two different commits (usually designated as branches). It doesn't replace one branch with another. If you want a production branch that is identical to master, throw away the existing production branch and start a new production branch at master. Actually, what people usually do in this situation is use a _tag_. For instance, I would simply attach a version tag to this master commit. That way, we all know that to release or test this version you check out this tag.

Comment: @Marc If you push a new commit to master, and merge from command line, how's the result?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - that helped. I added an extra space to the problematic line on master and committed this. This was then merged successfully into production! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved by pushing a new commit to master branch, and then merging to production branch.

Comment: As an explanation: the production branch was updated (line 236) to remove the change before the merge but AFTER the commit on master which introduced the change. It would seem git takes the latest change as the winner automatically which was incorrect in this case.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you didn't want a merge in the first place. And it sounds like you didn't need a `production` branch either! It seems that what you're trying to say is: "Hey, world, see this commit on `master`, namely `01785665a`? That is our "Release 4".

(That is not what you did say. What you said was: "Take some aspects of the existing `master` branch and some aspects of the existing `production` branch and mix them together and make a new hybrid thing called "Release 4." That's what you said, because that is what `merge` means. But it seems that that is not what you meant.)

The way to say what you appear to want to say is to *tag* this commit. For example, you might tag it as `r4`, meaning "Release 4". Now you know that in order to test or release Release 4, you checkout `r4` and archive it.

Henceforth the `master` branch may grow, but the special feature of a tag is that it remains forever attached to that one commit. So `r4` will stay right where it is, and you can check it out and return to it at any time.

Comment: For all I know, Azure DevOps may have a feature to help you do that directly at the remote. GitHub does; it has a thing called "releases", which basically applies the tag for you.

Comment: You are correct that I misunderstood merge. However is there no way to do this kind of versioning in it's own branch? The advantage I see is it's easier with tooling to compare branches. Also, everyone I know uses dev|test|prod branches.

Comment: Well, this is why I wanted us to talk about specific things you did in `master` that you found ended up not being present or correct in the merge commit. But you didn't want to. — If `master` could have been put directly onto the end of `production`, it would have been if you were on `production` and said `git merge --ff-only master`. But either you didn't say that or it wasn't possible. We can see from your log that you did not get a fast-forward of `master` onto `production`; you got a merge commit. So maybe your question is why. But you have hidden all the info needed to answer that.

Comment: I can go into specifics but not provide any source code: let's say on line 123 we have added the word `highlight=true` which is in commit `01785665a` (the last commit on `master`) but did not arrive in `production` and is not visible in `c1aa29bda` (the last commit on `production`). IMHO the merge just rejected the source branch's changes.

Comment: We're just waving our hands. I don't know what the actual situation is or even what `git` command you actually gave.

Comment: I'm trying to answer your question without posting my codebase online. We don't use git commands to merge PRs: it's done by Azure DevOps - Clicky Clicky...

Comment: Yes, I figured you'd say that. I'm afraid I don't know what Azure DevOps does or how to find out what it actually said to git.

Comment: Is there a way to mirror/copy a branch over to another branch. I think I see what went wrong...

Comment: Again, you’re using words in such an odd way that I don’t know what your question means. It would really have helped also if you had not elected to obscure the SHA info in the screen shot.